# How can I get the product name of the device connected to a USB port (Linux) in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, usb

I have two devices connected to their respective USB ports on a computer (running Ubuntu OS), each device will typically connect to the `/dev/ttyACM0` or `/dev/ttyACM1` ports. However, this is not fixed, and the devices may alternate between the ports listed previously.

To avoid errors in my C++ program, I therefore want to verify the devices' connecting ports.

**So my question is, how can I detect the product name of the device connected to a specific port in Linux using C++ (C++ 17)?**

---

Example:

Device: A Teensy 3.2 connected to `/dev/hidraw8`

Output of `dmesg -w` when I connect the device to the USB port:

```
[1876854.403461] usb 3-13: new full-speed USB device number 78 using xhci_hcd
[1876854.556946] usb 3-13: New USB device found, idVendor=16c0, idProduct=0486, bcdDevice= 2.75
[1876854.556957] usb 3-13: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[1876854.556960] usb 3-13: Product: Teensyduino RawHID
[1876854.556963] usb 3-13: Manufacturer: Teensyduino
[1876854.556965] usb 3-13: SerialNumber: 10164000
[1876854.561740] hid-generic 0003:16C0:0486.00BF: hiddev3,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Device [Teensyduino Teensyduino RawHID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-13/input0
[1876854.562791] hid-generic 0003:16C0:0486.00C0: hidraw8: USB HID v1.11 Device [Teensyduino Teensyduino RawHID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-13/input1
```

When I refer to the 'product name' in my question above I mean the `Product: Teensyduino RawHID` from line 4 in the logs above. The system obviously knows some information about my device, so I'm thinking I should able to retrieve it in my C++ code.

Comment: It‘s possible but not straightforward. Use a library like [libusbp](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp) or [libusb](https://github.com/libusb/libusb).

Comment: Parse the output of `lsusb` ?

Comment: While this is possible to solve, it is finicky and non-portable. What if you have three devices tomorrow? What if you change vendor?

The better solution is to [adapt your OS](https://superuser.com/questions/1323363/extra-created-dev-ttyusb-blocks-usage-of-custom-udev-config-ed-dev-file/1324783#1324783) to resolve each device to a unique file by means of a udev rule. Then you can just connect to `/dev/teensy_red` and `/dev/teensy_blue` or somesuch.